# Unknown class PlayerDetailsViewController in Interface Builder file

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

I am following [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/50310/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-2), and the App was working fine till i started implementing the delegate method.

please have a look at the classes "ViewController" and "PlayerDetailsViewController"

the error i am getting when I click either "Cancel" or "Done" button is,

**error**:

```
2017-06-01 13:55:47.620 Segue-1[3437:138735] Unknown class  
PlayerDetailsViewController in Interface Builder file.
2017-06-01 13:55:48.716 Segue-1[3437:138735] -[UITableViewController     
cancel:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7a85c0d0

2017-06-01 13:55:48.720 Segue-1[3437:138735] *** Terminating app due   
to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-   
[UITableViewController cancel:]: unrecognized selector sent to  
 instance 0x7a85c0d0'
```

** ViewController.h**:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@end
```

** ViewController.m**:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "PlayerDetailsViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a     
nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
   [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
   // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

 #pragma mark - PlayerDetailsViewControllerDelegate

- (void)playerDetailsViewControllerDidCancel:   
(PlayerDetailsViewController *)controller
{
   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
 }

 - (void)playerDetailsViewControllerDidSave:   
 (PlayerDetailsViewController *)controller
 {
     [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
 }


 @end
```

**PlayerDetailsViewController.h**:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class PlayerDetailsViewController;

@protocol PlayerDetailsViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)playerDetailsViewControllerDidCancel:  
(PlayerDetailsViewController *)controller;
 - (void)playerDetailsViewControllerDidSave: 
(PlayerDetailsViewController   
 *)controller;
 @end

@interface PlayerDetailsViewController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <PlayerDetailsViewControllerDelegate>   
delegate;

- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)done:(id)sender;

@end
```

**PlayerDetailsViewController.m**:

```
#import "PlayerDetailsViewController.h"

@interface PlayerDetailsViewController ()

@end

@implementation PlayerDetailsViewController

 - (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

 // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between   
 presentations.
 // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

 // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the 
 navigation bar for this view controller.
 // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
 }

 - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
     [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
     // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
 }

 - (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender
 {
    [self.delegate playerDetailsViewControllerDidCancel:self];
 }

 - (IBAction)done:(id)sender
 {
     [self.delegate playerDetailsViewControllerDidSave:self];
 }

 #pragma mark - Table view data source

 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
 #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 0;
 }

 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView   
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
 return 1;
 }
```

**update section**

UPDATE SECTION

//the below code is added to ViewController.m

```
     - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:  
      (id)sender
       {
        if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"AddPlayer"]) {

       UINavigationController *navigationController =   
       segue.destinationViewController;
       PlayerDetailsViewController *playerDetailsViewController = 
        [navigationController viewControllers][0];
        playerDetailsViewController.delegate = self;
       }
      }
```

Comment: You have change any thing in Storyboard ?

Comment: It looks like you might have a couple issues... First, are you setting the delegate in `PlayersViewController.m`? If so, can you show that code?

Comment: playerDetailsViewController.delegate = self;
 Watch out this line in prepareForSegue method in PlayersViewController. You may have missed it from tutorial.

Comment: @DonMag after reading ur comment i added the delegate as you suggested…please have a look at the update section above..but what i am not sure about is ..I do not know what my segue identifier is called..according to the code in the update section it is called "if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"AddPlayer"])"..would you please tell me how can i find out the name of my segue identifier?

Comment: @DonMag I posted my update

Comment: @jegadeesh please find the code in the update section…..would u also let me know how to find out what my segue identifier is actually called?

Comment: @user2121 - in Storyboard, you've probably created the segue by ctrl-drag. Select that segue, and in the Attributes Inspector you'll see a field for "Identifier"

Comment: @DonMag ok i found it.but know when i click the Add button which is in the 2st scene the App crashes and i get the following errors: 16:04:53.093 Segue-1[3919:176794] Unknown class PlayerDetailsViewController in Interface Builder file.
2017-06-01 16:04:53.098 Segue-1[3919:176794] -[UITableViewController setDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7902c500
2017-06-01 16:04:53.103 Segue-1[3919:176794] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewController setDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7902c500'

Comment: @user2121 - yeah, that's why my first comment was that you might have a couple issues... I'd suggest going back a step or two if you can. It sounds like you assigned `PlayerDetailsViewController` to a view controller in your Storyboard, but missed a connection somewhere. Really tough to say without seeing your whole project.